# Url reverse error

Tags: django

I've got a url with two fields user_id and code:

```
url(r'^account_completion/(?P<user_id>d+)$/(?P<code>[-w]+)$', confirm_verification, name="confirmation_link"),
```

I've tried getting the link from the shell got an error

```
In [2]: reverse('confirmation_link', args=(123,'aaaaaaa'))/home/samuel/Documents/code/kazi/django_project/django_project/urls.py:34: 
  t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoReverseMatch                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...
...

NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'confirmation_link' with arguments '(123, 'aaaaaaa')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['register/account_completion/(?P<user_id>d+)$/(?P<code>[-w]+)$']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your url regex. Try the following:

```
url(r'^account_completion/(?P<user_id>\d+)/(?P<code>[-\w]+)$',
    confirm_verification, name="confirmation_link"),
```